# How to filter nothing in r

Tags: r, filter

I was wondering how you would filter nothing in r?

For example I would like this to return the full dataset:

---

data("iris")

iris %>%
filter(Species == "(.*?)")

---

Thanks!

Comment: `iris %>% filter(TRUE)`

Comment: @Waldi, please post as an answer.

Comment: if you want to be more literal about "Species is anything", you could use `iris %>% filter(stringr::str_detect(Species, "^.*$"))`